# What is more efficient, a massive RegEx, or thousands of .startsWith calls?

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, startswith

I'm writing a JavaScript application, and I'm parsing user input which comes in the format of "book name location in book".

Examples of possible inputs:

- The First Book Ch. 2
- A Monograph of Text Pg. 3
- The Different Codex 5:4

I have a list of around 5000 possible book names, each of which has multiple variations of how the location in the book can be formatted. Since the book name always comes first, I want to search through the list of books to find which book matches the input, and then parse the rest of the input. Which of the following methods would be more efficient:

**Option 1**

```
var input = "The First Book Ch. 2";
var books = [
  "The First Book",
  "A Monograph of Text",
  //5000 more entries
];
var regex = new RegExp("^" + books.join("|"));
var isMatch = input.match(regex);
```

**Option 2**

```
var input = "The First Book Ch. 2";
var books = [
  "The First Book",
  "A Monograph of Text",
  //5000 more entries
];
var regex = new RegExp("^" + books.join("|"));
var isMatch = false;
for ( var i = 0; i < books.length; i++ ) {
  if ( input.startsWith( books[i] ) ) {
    isMatch = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Two questions:

- In a front-end application (running in the user's browser), which is faster, option 1, option 2, or is there a third, faster option?
- I also have a back-end application (running in Node.js), where I need to parse large texts (~500,000 characters or more), and for every parentheses in the text, I need to perform this match (e.g. around 2,000-3,000 strings to match against the list of books). What would be the most efficient option for this use-case?

Comment: Just intuitively, `.startsWith` looks for a literal string, whereas a regex invokes an entire parsing/compiling process. It might be a very quick process, but relatively speaking it's significantly more than just a raw string.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol on the other hand, each .startsWith is another function call, with all the overhead that entails. I'm really hoping someone has a third option, especially for my second use case.

Comment: In stead of asking which is fastest, try doing benchmarking yourself. I've been surprised over and over again once I started actually measuring.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the execution of your code with the [performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) API.

```js
const t0 = performance.now();
console.log(runCodeToMeasure());
const t1 = performance.now();

console.log('Took ', (t1 - t0).toFixed(4), ' milliseconds to run.');
```